# How to move drop down menu, menu to the left?

Tags: html, css

```
.head_menu
{
    height:30px;
    line-height:30px;
    color:#FFF;
    position:absolute;
    font-family:Arial;
    font-size:15px;
    right:15px;
    z-index:2;
    top:3px;

}
.head_menu ul
{
    padding:0px;
    margin:0;
    list-style:none;
}
.head_menu ul li
{
    padding:0;
    margin:0;
    float:left;

}
.head_menu ul li a
{
    color:#FFF;
    display:block;
    text-decoration:none;

}
.head_menu ul li a:hover
{

    color:#FFF;
    text-decoration:underline;
    text-shadow: 0 0 10px #FFF;
}
.head_menu ul li ul a:hover
{
    background:#e17310;
}
.head_menu ul li ul
{
     display: none;
     width: auto;
     position:absolute;
     top:30px;
     padding:0px;
     margin:0px;

}
.head_menu ul li:hover ul
{
     display:block;     
     position:absolute;
     margin: 0;
     padding: 0;
}
.head_menu ul li:hover li
{
    float: none;
    list-style:none;
    margin:0px;

}
.head_menu ul li:hover li
{
    background:#e7a017;
}
.head_menu ul li:hover li a
{
    color: #FFF;
    padding:0 20px;
    display:block;
    width:80px;
}
.head_menu ul li li a:hover
{
    color:#FFF;
}
```

thats my code and the drop down menu looks like this.

http://s18.postimg.org/612nvikmh/Untitled.jpg

(sorry if its flipped idk why but when I uploaded it it flipped that way)

can you guys help me move it to the left to show the full menu? I've been trying to solve this for an hour now and can't seem to find a fix for it on the internet, and I am now very confused as hell.

thanks everyone!

Comment: @Ken Kushida, for this kind of questions I would recommend you to use http://jsfiddle.net/ and paste the link here.

Comment: I can't seem to load jsfiddle.net..I have no clue why...taking too long to respond. I'll check back again later. very sorry guys been an inconvenience.

Answer (score 0):

Try to put the menu in a div container and Then set this container `float:left;`
Or you could set width and use `margin:0 auto;`to center it.
And you need to delete the `position: absoulte;`from `.head_menu`

http://jsfiddle.net/Ucvbu/

Comment: it is in a Div container. when I remove the "position:abosulte" the "support" disappears.

Answer (score 0):

```
.head_menu
{
height:30px;
line-height:30px;
color:#FFF;
position:absolute;
font-family:Arial;
font-size:15px;
left:15px;
z-index:2;
top:3px;

}
```

Comment: That just actually moved the "support" to the left,I'd really like to keep it in the right and just adjust the drop down menu so it could be seen fully. 

is there no way I could do that? T^T

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is, we can set the negative value to the padding, so set the negative value to margin-right. Then increase the right padding to the  so that it dropdown is aligned correctly.

```
.head_menu ul li:hover ul
{
     display:block;     
     position:absolute;
     margin-right:-20px;
     padding: 0;

}



.head_menu ul li:hover li a
{
    color: #FFF;
    padding:0 20px;
    display:block;
    width:80px;
    padding-right:10px;
}
```